# how to use youtube-g ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, youtube

new to rails and trying to get youtube-g to work... I am having a difficult time passing a users search from the form_tag to the controller.. for example:

1. user lands on page, enters - tiger videos - in text_field_tag
2. controller takes - tiger videos - and searches
3. user lands on another page displaying the results...
4. user lands on page, enters query

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(youtube_path) do %> 
    <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %> 
    <%= text_field_tag(:wth) %> 
    <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
    <% end %>
```

--

1. controller takes query and searches

youtubecontroller.rb

```
class YoutubeController < ApplicationController
def search
  require 'youtube_g'
  client = YouTubeG::Client.new
client.videos_by(:query => params[:wth])
end
end
```

--

my routes file:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
map.search “search”, :controller => “youtube”
```

I havn´t got to step 3 yet..

what I want is a page with just a text box and a submit button, and when a user enters text and submits, they are brought to a new page that renders 10 youtube results. any help is much appreciated!!!

http://youtube-g.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

search.html.erb

```
 <%= form_tag(:action => "search") do %> 
      <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %> 
      <%= text_field_tag(:wth) %> 
      <%= submit_tag("Search") %>  
 <% end %>
```

YoutubeController

```
require 'youtube_g'
class YoutubeController < ApplicationController
  def index         
  end

  def search  
    if request.post?
     client = YouTubeG::Client.new
     @youtube = client.videos_by(:query => params[:wth],:per_page => 10)         
     render :action => :index
    end 
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @youtube.videos.each do |video| %>
   <%= video.title %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
 map.resources :youtube, :collection => { :search => :get }
```

Comment: HI thank you for your response! I was able to get results showing.. but the form in search.html.erb does not display.. when I navigate to http://0.0.0.0:3000/youtube/search rather than a form displaying, it automatically renders search results.. this is what it spits out 

#, @media_content=[#, @default=true, @url="http://www.youtube.com/v/NkfuPTm1zUo?f=videos&app=youtube_gdata">], @title="X-Men Evolution: Season 3, Episode 3", @published_at=Wed Mar 04 20:45:26 UTC 2009, @duration=1285, @thumbnails=[#, #, #, #], @player_url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkfuPTm1zUo&feature=youtube_gdat...

Comment: Sorry. I don't test. I have just update my code. please see again. I tested it. It's ok. Hope it'll helpful for you. :)